# Replacing sun.misc.Base64 with javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter

Tags: java, java-6

I'm working with a project that uses sun.misc.base64encoder and decoder a couple of times in it, but the package no longer worked when I tried to take over. So i'm trying to use the javax.xml.bind.DataTypeConverter class instead. I'm using Java 6 so I can't use the util.Base64, this is the best alternative to my knowledge.

Luckily, it only uses the sun.misc packages a couple of times in the whole program, so the change was going smoothly, until I ran into the following...

```
try {
            byte[] utf8 = textToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF8");
            byte[] enc = encryptionCypher.doFinal(utf8);
            return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);

        } catch (javax.crypto.BadPaddingException e) {
            throw new EncryptException(e.toString(), e);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            throw new EncryptException(e.toString(), e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new EncryptException(e.toString(), e);
        }
```

i'm trying to keep it as similar to the original code as possible, so as to avoid any major hiccups later on. So here is what I tried changing it to.

```
try {
            byte[] utf8 = textToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF8");
            byte[] enc = encryptionCypher.doFinal(utf8);
            //return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);
            return new DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(enc);

        } catch (javax.crypto.BadPaddingException e) {
            throw new EncryptException(e.toString(), e);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            throw new EncryptException(e.toString(), e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new EncryptException(e.toString(), e);
        }
```

When I tried this however, it treated printBase64Primary as a class, and wouldn't let me run the function the way I intended. I would like to know if there are any ways to fix this, or if there are any more suitable alternatives. I mean my first idea would be to just get rid of the "new" but I'm worried there's a reason it's there. Also I don't want to use any other java versions if I can avoid it, since this is such a small part of the program.

I should also mention i'm using Apache Netbeans, if that helps.

Comment: `printBase64Binary` is not a `static` method so you need an instance of `DatatypeConverter`. Now your `new` call is wrong as you are missing the `()` so it should read `new DatatypeConverter().printBase64Binary(ene)`;

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried that, but it sais that DatatypeConverter had private privileges

Comment: All `DatatypeConverter` methods are static, just remove the `new` keyword. BTW, since JAXB has been removed from Java SE 9, you should create your own method to convert to/from Base64: when you'll upgrade to a more recent Java version you'll just have to change one method.

Comment: Hmm. Weird I must have been looking at something different. It is indeed `static` and thus you need to remove the `new` part to call the method correctly.